# JHipster and IntelliJ JPA Console

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster

Using JHipster 4.2.0 in IntelliJ the jpa console is not working:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Entities] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
```

While in application-dev.yml the factory_class is set.

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: This usually happens when you did not set spring profile to dev, check IJ settings

Comment: I have set the spring dev profile in Run/Debug Configurations and in Maven Profiles but don't know how to set it for the jpa console.

Comment: JPA console being a feature of Ultimate Edition, have you asked JetBrains support? Or just this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-the-jpa-console.html#d469049e34

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create this persistence.xml file in the resources folder, but you need to fix to fit your needs, in my case I'm using postgresSQL but you can config with your data base type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="project name" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- non-jta-datasource>jdbc/arquillian</non-jta-datasource -->
        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
           <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
           <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
           <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
           <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dialysis-dev"/>
           <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="develop"/>
           <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admpostgres"/>
           <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
           <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy"/>
           <property name="hibernate.ddl-auto" value="none"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Then in view menu/Tools Windows/Persistence you will be able to see this persistence file. So with right click you can see JPA console. In my case works perfectly.

Using this way you do not need to assign datasource because all config needed by IntelliJ IDEA is in the above file. By the way this was tested in the Ultimate version of Intellij IDEA.